# Put Seaborn FacetGrid into Axes of Subplots

Tags: python, seaborn

In Seaborn I can specify on which axis a plot should be drawn like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [7, 6, 2], "c": ["x", "x", "y"]})
_, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="a", y="b", hue="c", ax=ax1)
```

Now my question is: I want to put a FacetGrid into an existing axis like so:

```
sns.FacetGrid(df, ax=ax1)
```

But FacetGrid has no parameter called *ax*.
How can I achieve this in a different way?

Update 1: I did some research and figured out, that FacetGrid produces its own Matplotlib Figure instance. So the solution which is probably the best would be to use `Figure.subfigures()` as described in [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subfigures-py)

Comment: please, provide reproducible code. Code helps us understand the question

Comment: Is this clearer now?

Comment: `FacetGrid` is typically meant to create a figure with multiple subplots. The `ax=` parameter would only indicate one subplot. As there are many unsolved questions in how a `FacetGrid` could work with an existing `Figure`, such functionality isn't supported by current Seaborn versions. Working with matplotlib's new  `subfigure` concept is one of the avenues being explored, but there still are many open questions.

Comment: In the meantime (pending Seaborn to figure it out how to make it work with matplotlib `subfigure`), and I understand that this is far from being ideal, when facing with this limitation and wanting to create a multi-panel figure, you can save the figure as a high-res PNG and plot it as an image (`imshow`) within a gridspec/subplots.